# assigning data attributes to divs in less?

Tags: css, facebook, html, facebook-like, less

I was wondering if you could assign data attributes to divs, because I am adding a fb-like-box to my html and want to customize the fb box in less, as much as possible.

It uses data-height, data-width, data-header, among others to customize the fb-like-box

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-height="300px" data-width="240px" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

Is there a way to do something like this in less?

```
.fb-like-box {
  .data-height(300px);
  .data-width(240px);
  .data-stream(true);
}
```

So the html could look like:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"></div>
```

I know I could do this using js, but was wondering if it can be done using less first.

Comment: No, LESS doesn't touch the DOM tree.

Comment: @Brad LESS is compiled to pure CSS on client side, so you can do whatever you can inside of normal CSS. It's just a nice tool for front-end devs to write CSS using less characters, rules and etc. =)